# What do the function blocks mean?

Tags: impulse-response

[image]

What I don't understand is what `exp(.)` and `ln(.)` mean. For example `y(t)` and `x(t)` have `exp(.)` between them. What exactly does that mean? `y(t)=`?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. **Complete answers to homework are off-topic**, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: For extra credit, explain to your professor why it's invalid to apply the concept of "impulse response" to that system.  For extra-extra credit, explain why doing the $\ln(\cdot)$ operation first is slightly less invalid.  For super-extra credit, write out a system description that properly uses the rules of real analysis to show that the impulse response that the professor thinks will happen will, in fact, happen.

Comment: @TimWescott the z(x) system looks pretty LTI to me, what's wrong with describing it with an impulse response? (the y(x) and the z(y) systems certainly don't).

Comment: It's the interior nonlinearities that are giving me gas.  If you were to flop that block diagram in front of my eyes in a work environment and say that's a description of the system, I'd want to make very sure that any of the inevitable undocumented low- (and possibly band-) pass processes acting on $y(t)$ are fast enough that they don't matter for the task at hand -- and I might ask you to document the upper bound of frequency and amplitude where that assumption would still be valid.

Comment: Given the edit, this should be re-opened.  In a block diagram, $f(\cdot)$ means "act on the input with the function $f$", (usually in the time domain).  So in the block diagram above, $y(t) = \exp(x(t))$.

Comment: @TimWescott Reopened, and restated question.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is what exp(.) and ln(.) mean. For example y(t) and x(t) have exp(.) between them. What exactly does that mean?

$f(\cdot)$ inside a block means that you should apply $f$ *in the time domain* to the input.

> y(t)=?

So $y(t) = e^{x(t)}$, $z(t) = \ln y(t)$.  In theory, in turn that means that $z(t) = x(t)$.  In practice there's all sorts of difficulties, because of the nonlinearities "under the hood".  But to the extent that practice follows theory, it'll fly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write the relationship between $z(t)$ and $x(t)$ and then simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the notation $\exp(\cdot)$, the argument is point-wise, and sometimes called a scalar operation. So for each $x(t)$, you will replace the $\cdot$ by $x(t)$, hence for instance  $\exp(x(t))$. The rest could flow.